# Как оживить control value accessor?

Tags: javascript, angular2, typescript

Пытаюсь разобраться с control value accessor и набросал простейший пример. В каждой функции поставил консоль лог чтобы посмотреть в какой именно момент она срабатывает.

Проблема в том, что ни одна из этих функций не срабатывает. Хотя при этом ошибок в консоли нет. И вообще я реализовал интерфейс control value accessor поэтому должно хоть что-то происходить

Помогите пожалуйста оживать пример. [Демо здесь](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vicfdg)

js:

```
  name: FormGroup;

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.name = fb.group({
      firstName:['1'],
      lastName: ['22']
    });
  }

  writeValue(value: any) {
    console.log('writeValue', value);
    if(value) {
        this.name.setValue(value);
    }
  }


  registerOnChange(fn: (value: any) => void) {
    console.log('registerOnChange');
    this.name.valueChanges.subscribe(fn);
  }

  registerOnTouched() {
    console.log('registerOnTouched');
  }
```

html:

```
  <div [formGroup]="name">
    <input formControlName="firstName">
    <input formControlName="lastName">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`control value accessor` используется для реализации `ngModel` в кастомном компоненте. Потому ваша в данный момент и не работает. Вот пример реализации `control value accessor`:

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-custom-component',
templateUrl: './app-custom.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app-custom.component.scss'],
providers: [
        {
            provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
            useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomComponent),
            multi: true
        }
    ]
})
export class CustomComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
    private _begin: Date;
    set begin(value) {
        this._begin = value;
        this.onChange(this._begin);
    }

    get begin() {
        return this._begin;
    }        

    onChange = (_: any) => { };
    OnTouched = (_: any) => { };

    constructor() { }

    writeValue(value: Date): void {
        this.begin = value;
    }

    registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
        this.onChange= fn;
    }

    registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
        this.onTouched= fn;
    }

    setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
        /*реализация для свойства disabled*/
    }
}
```

В разметке компоненты:

```
<input type="date" [(ngModel)]="begin" name="begin">
```

Непосредственное использование:

```
<app-custom-component [(ngModel)]="currentDate"></app-custom-component>
```

В компоненте объявить свойство `currentDate`

Как то так.